# Swap on void* array doesn't work correctly

Tags: c, arrays, void-pointers

I have an array of complex numbers, and I just want to swap between two elements. However, I want to implement the swap for unknown types (using void*). So I wrote the following code, using the first swap implementation that I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16543052/swap-items-of-void-pointer-array-without-memcpy-in-c):

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct complex complex;

struct complex {
    int real;
    int img;
};

void swap(void *arr[], int i, int j)
{
    void *temp;
    temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}

void printComplexArray(complex* cArr, size_t len)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        printf("Cell %d : real- %d , img- %d\n", i, cArr[i].real, cArr[i].img);
    }
}

void main(void)
{
    complex cArr[] = { { 22, 3 },{ 1, 13 },{ 5, 7 },{ 8, 4 } };
    size_t cLen = (sizeof(cArr) / sizeof(cArr[0]));
    swap(cArr, 1, 2);
    printComplexArray(cArr, cLen);
}
```

I expected to get:

```
Cell 0 : real- 22 , img- 3
Cell 1 : real- 5 , img- 7
Cell 2 : real- 1 , img- 13
Cell 3 : real- 8 , img- 4
```

But I got:

```
Cell 0 : real- 22 , img- 1
Cell 1 : real- 3 , img- 13
Cell 2 : real- 5 , img- 7
Cell 3 : real- 8 , img- 4
```

As you can see, not only that the swapping wasn't performed correctly- the content of some array elements was changed. Can you explain why, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Any reason you can't just use `complex.h` with its superior support?

Comment: Yes, I'm not allowed to include any h files (besides stdio.h)

Comment: `complex cArr[]` is not `void *arr[]`... You should look at compiler warnings...

Comment: @LPs , I don't get any warning (using visual studio). Can you tell how to declare cArr correctly so that I won't have this problem?

Answer (score 6):

You probably want this:

```
void swap(struct complex arr[], int i, int j)
{
    struct complex temp;
    temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}
```

Your solution swaps *pointers* but your array doesn't contain pointers but `struct complex`s. That's basically what the compiler warning told you.

If you really want to swap unknown types, you need this:

```
void swap(void *arr, int i, int j, size_t size)
{
    char temp[size];
    char *a = (char*)arr;

    memcpy(temp, (a + size * i), size);
    memcpy((a + size * i), (a + size * j), size);
    memcpy((a + size * j), temp, size);
}
...
swap(cArr, 1, 2, sizeof(*cArr));
```

The size parameter is necessary because if the type is unknown, the size of the type is of course unknown too and therefore you need to specify the size.

For `memcpy` you need to include `<memory.h>`, so you must write your own `memcpy`, as you are allowed to include only `<stdio.h>`.

Some compilers won't allow `char temp[size];` so you just can use `char temp[MAX_SIZE];` with `MAX_SIZE` defined to the maximum expected size for your unknown types.

Comment: I don't get any warning (using visual studio). Anyway, I must use void* in my swap. Can you tell how can I change my code so that I will be able to use swap with void* arr?

Comment: @Rodrigo Read the last sentence of this answer. Your array doesn't contain pointers. Therefore there are no `void*` to swap. This answer is correct for the task you've posted, so either your instruction isn't clear or was misunderstood.

Comment: Should be `swap(cArr, 1, 2, sizeof(   *   cArr));` (size of single element, not whole array); alternative to tmp[MAX_SIZE] (if no maximum imposition is desired) might be using malloc/free or - where available - even alloca.

Comment: @Aconcagua thanks for the `sizeof( * cArr)`. Using `malloc/free` is possible, but expensive, and `alloca` is deprecated but inexpensive.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Well, the C99's variable length array `char tmp[size]` certainly is best option anyway - just wanted to give hints to alternatives not imposing size limits (and possibly allocating far too large memory in other cases, btw...). Should have mentioned the disadvantages myself. Hm, alloca is not documented as deprecated, at least on the linux sites I looked at (MSVC does so, though). If it actually is, then probably in favour to exactly these variable length arrays...

Answer (score 1):

You can't implement swap for unknown type, You need to know the size of the type. Your function swaps pointers (pointers have known size), but You are feeding it array of `complex`, not an array of pointers. Try this (not tested):

```
void swap(void *array, size_t i, size_t j, size_t element_length) {

    char *src, *dst, tmp;

    src = (char*)array + i * element_length;
    dst = (char*)array + j * element_length;

    while (element_length--) {

        tmp = *src;
        *src = *dst;
        *dst = tmp;

        src++;
        dst++;
    }
}

...

swap(cArr, 1, 2, sizeof(complex));
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do so using `void *` (as far as I can see) is to re-design your `swap` function swapping/coping byte of structs, like

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct complex complex;

struct complex {
    int real;
    int img;
};


void swap(void * to, void * from, size_t len)
{
    unsigned char *uc_to   = to;
    unsigned char *uc_from = from;
    unsigned char tmp;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        tmp = uc_to[i];
        uc_to[i] = uc_from[i];
        uc_from[i] = tmp;
    }
}

void printComplexArray(complex* cArr, size_t len)
{
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        printf("Cell %zu : real- %02d , img- %02d\n", i, cArr[i].real, cArr[i].img);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    complex cArr[] = { { 22, 3 }, { 1, 13 }, { 5, 7 }, { 8, 4 } };

    size_t cLen = (sizeof(cArr) / sizeof(cArr[0]));

    swap((void *)(&cArr[0]), (void *)(&cArr[1]), sizeof(complex));

    printComplexArray(cArr, cLen);
}
```